# Social Media Issue

Tags: wordpress

When I uploaded link of my website to the social media It pulls the logo and add display white on white which looks bad. Is there any way to fix this without changing the logo?
Here is the screenshot:[image]

Answer (score 1):

You must set true open graph tag for your website

Read the documents [here](http://ogp.me/)

Your logo can set by this tag:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
```

Comment: I have added this meta tag but still the same issue is there :(

Comment: taniya, go to view source and copy image url in the og tag and open that url in new tab, and check logo for it's view, may be you logo have a problem from wordpress to view, not from og tag!

Comment: Can you please check that what is the issue with the logo?

Answer (score 0):

I checked your eg tag, it's correct, but may be your social media has specific size for image, check for that size and then use of these tag, this may be solve your problem:

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="150" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="150" />
```

Although you must consider every social have different size, for example i see your logo in telegram like this image

[image]

I advice consider an square logo, not an rectangular logo

Comment: <meta property="og:image:width" content="150" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="150" /> I have added these meta tags to the head section. Can you please check it again on the telegram?

Comment: I checked again, not work, go to square solution ;-)

Comment: Yes added the square logo now but having issue on the facebook messenger

Answer (score 0):

Different Socials may be have different og tags

for example facebook and twitter have special tags for themselves

if you use wordpress you can use of this [plugin](https://fa.wordpress.org/plugins/wonderm00ns-simple-facebook-open-graph-tags/)